# Wrap around a specific div

Tags: jquery

I tried `Wrap` and `WrapALl` and also `nextUntil` but its quite tricky this one. I have this html

```
     <ul class="quick-list quick-glance hideOnSearch show-for-medium-up">
       <li><span class="strong">Price:</span> $198000</li>
       <li><span class="strong">Miles:</span> 349999</li>
       <li><span class="strong">Vehicle Type:</span> Minivans and Vans</li>
     </ul>
```

and I want it to look like

```
    <ul class="accordion show-for-small hide-for-medium-up">
      <li>
        <div class="title">TITLE</div>
        <div class="content"> 
         
             <ul class="quick-list quick-glance hideOnSearch show-for-medium-up">
               <li><span class="strong">Price:</span> $198000</li>
               <li><span class="strong">Miles:</span> 349999</li>
               <li><span class="strong">Vehicle Type:</span> Minivans and Vans</li>
             </ul>
        
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

I tried this

```
$('ul.quick-list').wrapAll('<ul class="accordion"><li><div class="title">TITLE</div><div class="content"></div></li></ul>'); //Single page Top accordion
```

But it places `quick-list` in the wrong places.

How can I do it with jQuery?

Comment: Please show the code you tried. Hard to tell what went wrong without seeing it.

Comment: Added it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapAll() only supports one inner element, you have two. Solution:

```
$('ul.quick-list').wrap('<ul class="accordion"><li><div class="content"></div></li></ul>');
$('.content').before('<div class="title">TITLE</div>');
```

See an example: http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/HzDCD/1/

Comment: Thanks. But this solution pushed `div.title` to the bottom of `div.content` so I fixed it with this `$('.accordion li div.content').before('<div class="title">TITLE</div>');` If you can please edit the answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

try this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/8gCR4/1/)**

```
$(function(){
$('ul.quick-list').wrap('<ul class="accordion show-for-small hide-for-medium-up">').wrap("<li>").wrap('<div class="content">');

$('.content').before('<div class="title">TITLE</div>');
});
```